# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: error

Tags: c++

So I created a helper function in a different class and it doesn't compile.

This is the error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "move(sc2::Unit const*, sc2::Unit const*)", referenced from:
      Ihurt_Multi_Unit_Bot::OnStep() in battle_simulator.cc.o
```

where I call it, it's the move function.

```
virtual void OnStep()
{   
    Units alive = Observation()->GetUnits();
    for (int i = 0; i<alive.size(); i++)
    {
        if (alive[i]->unit_type == 9)
            enemy = alive[i];

        if ((Observation()->GetGameLoop() % 2) == 0)
        {
            if (alive[i]->unit_type == 48) 
            {
                move(alive[i], enemy);
            }

        }
```

the class of the function

```
void move(const Unit* unit, const Unit* enemy);

class commands : public Agent 
{
    commands() = default;
    void move(const Unit* unit, const Unit* enemy)
    { 
        Point2D moveto;
        double path = Query()->PathingDistance(unit->pos, enemy->pos);

        if (path < Observation()->GetUnitTypeData()[enemy->unit_type].weapons.front().range) 
        {
            moveto = getBestMove(unit->pos, enemy->pos);
            Actions()->UnitCommand(unit, ABILITY_ID::MOVE, moveto);
        }
    }
```

Comment: where's your implementation of the `move` function? I can only see an implementation of the `commands::move` method?

Comment: You've _declared_ two different functions with the same name, and almost the same signature, but only _defined_ one. You wrote code to call the _other_ one. Is this the first time you've tried using methods? Did you mean the method to be a `friend`?

Comment: in the onstep() function

Comment: The `OnStep()` function _calls_ `move`. Do you know what function `move` refers to? Where is that function _defined_?

Comment: I'm new to c++ but I'm not new to programming. How have I declared two different functions. I just need one move function in a different file.

Comment: the move function is just a method that i don't want in the class that has onstep(), and i'm sorry, im not fully understaning

Comment: my bad the point2D i call it something else now but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: In your second code block you declare `move` once, as a free function, at file scope. Then you declare _and_ define a method of class `commands` with the same name. These are two different functions, called with different syntaxes. Only one of them is defined, and it's not the one you call. This is - in the nicest possible way - super basic stuff and you might benefit from reading an introductory book.

Answer (score 1):

If we reduce your code down to a minimal example it might be more obvious what the problem is:

```
void move();

class commands
{
public:
   void move()
   {
   }
};

int main()
{
    move();
}
```

You've declared and are calling a free function `move` but have only defined a method `move` inside the `commands` class.

Depending on what you are trying to achieve there are a number of ways of solving this. The best is probably just to remove the move function and call the method:

```
class commands
{
public:
   void move()
   {
   }
};

int main()
{
    commands cmds;
    cmds.move();
}
```

Comment: thanks, that was it